# Save lyx document using plain text instead of binary format

Tags: lyx

Saving a `.lyx` file produces a binary version of the file, which makes it hard to track changes in git. Is there a way to tell lyx to save files in some text format? Not plain text, something that retains all the formatting.

LyX Version 2.3.0 on macOS.

Answer (score 2):

The .lyx file format is actually text by default. It is possible that your LyX has the preference set to save files with compression by default, which would make them binary. To turn this preference off, go to Tools > Preferences > Look & Feel > Document Handling and uncheck "Save new documents compressed by default". See also the following answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330529/12212

Comment: I haven't changed any preferences after installing it and that preference is already unchecked. https://i.imgur.com/c8WAR6A.png. Is there a way to explicitly specify which version is saved? Maybe the document I have was saved as compressed before.

Comment: @waspinator can you please upload a minimal example .lyx file somewhere and link to it in your question? I don't think you can upload a binary file directly here.

Answer (score 0):

To save a compressed .lyx file in plain text,
uncheck `Document`->`Compressed`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!